# complex analysis integral with $z^8$ function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

can anyone help with this integral I'm trying to do. Will a semicircle contour work for this function?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{8}} dx$$

Comment: It's not the contour I'd use, but it will work.

Comment: How would you approach it, I'd ideally like to use the best method. Thanks!

Comment: You will have a bit too many residues with semicircle. Try to use the contour that looks like a pizza slice.

Comment: It facilitates to use the contour that is comprised of the (1) line segment from $0$ to $R$, (ii) circular arc from $R$ to $Re^{i\pi/4}$, and (iii) the line segment from $Re^{i\pi/4}$ to $0$.  This contour encloses only one pole at $z=e^{i\pi/8}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our analysis would be considerably streamlined by judiciously choosing the enclosing contour.  Accordingly, we choose the contour $C_R$ that is comprised of the (1) line segment from $0$ to $R$, (ii) circular arc from $R$ to $Re^{i\pi/4}$, and (iii) the line segment from $Re^{i\pi/4}$ to $0$.

Note that for $R>1$, $C_R$ encloses only the pole at $z=e^{i\pi/8}$.  Proceeding, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_R}\frac{1}{1+z^8}\,dz&=\int_0^R \frac{1}{1+x^8}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{1+R^8e^{i8\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_R^0 \frac{1}{1+t^8}\,e^{i\pi/4}\,dt\\\\
&=(1-e^{i\pi/4})\int_0^R \frac{1}{1+x^8}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{1+R^8e^{i8\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^8},z=e^{i\pi/8}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \lim_{z\to e^{i\pi/8}}\frac{z-e^{i\pi/8}}{1+z^8}\\\\
&=2\pi i\frac{1}{8e^{i7\pi/8}}
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\to \infty$ we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^8}\,dx=2\pi i\frac{1}{8e^{i7\pi/8}(1-e^{i\pi/4})}=\frac{\pi}{8\sin(\pi/8)}$$

Comment: thanks for this it's really helpful and has made a lot of the question clear to me now. Only one thing, how do you know that for R>1, only the pole at $e^{\frac{i\pi}{8}}$ is enclosed?

Comment: Well, all of the poles are on the unit circle at $z=e^{i\pi/8 + n\pi/4}$ for $n=0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 $.  So, if we choose our contour as described with $R>1$, then the only one of these poles that is enclosed is the one for $n=0$.

Comment: This answer is great and I think I now understand all aspects of the question so thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. Using that approach, you will get that the integral is eual to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $(1+z^8)^{-1}$ at $\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}8\right)$,  $\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}8\right)$, $\exp\left(\frac{5\pi i}8\right)$, and  $\exp\left(\frac{7\pi i}8\right)$. And, if $\omega$ is one of these numbers, the ridues there is eual to $\dfrac1{8\omega^7}$.

Comment: Thanks! How exactly did you get those values for the residues? Sorry if that seems an obvious question but I'm new to complex analysis so still working out the basic ideas of it all

Comment: @Josh Those are the roots of $z^8+1$ that belong to the upper half-plane.

Comment: So there are 8 roots to $z^{8}$ but we discount 4 of them as they don't lie in the upper half plane?

Comment: @Josh Yes, that is right.